# Mist does not show my outgoing transactions & does not show DIGIX or TheDAO tokens!

Tags: transactions, mist, wallets, tokens, bug

Ever since I downloaded Mist version **Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-7-5**
I can no longer see any of my outgoing transaction history or any of my DAO Tokens. When I add new tokens or crowd sale contracts it shows my tokens only until I close Mist. When I start Mist again, the tokens are no longer there and I have to add them all over again every time I restart Mist.

I think that I accidentally may have deleted a file. I am not sure why, but Mist is no longer recording my outgoing transactions and my last 2 outgoing transactions have failed.

I am now having the same issue with all versions of Mist! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: sounds like a bug to me. have you tried to contact the developers so far?

Comment: How do I contact them? Thank You.

Comment: Via github, https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues